# creating Uibinder multiple instances.

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a widget using UiBinder "MyTable" and another widget using UiBinder "MyTableElement". I want to add multiple instances of MyTableElement inn MyTable. I am adding the element on clickevent. MyTableElement gets added first time but it hangs if I add more widgets.
How should I create multiple instances of MyTableElement widget.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the browser.
Got fixed automatically.